# Problem with same resource, accessible via two routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, rails-routing

I'm developing simple image sharing site to train my ruby-on-rails-fu. I have following resources in my `config/routes.rb` file.

```
resources :users do
  resources :images
end

resources :images
```

Here's the problem I'm facing - how should I go about implementing functionality like "latest images" and "your image subscriptions"? Having vanilla resource url's here's how it looks now:

```
/users/N/images # ImagesController#index action for listing all images for a user
/images # ImagesController#index action for listing all possible images from all users.
```

How would you go about managing the "parent" object of images when accessing index action in images controller? Would simple check for `:user_id` in `params` hash suffice? Are there any plugins I'm not aware of (since I could not think of a simple description for this problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assign one to another controller, so that you won't mix them up and confuse yourself.

```
resources :users do
  resources :images, :controller => user_images
end

resources :images
```

Now in `user_images_controller`, you may consider getting the user object by before_filter (cause it depends on a given user :D)

```
UserImagesController
  before_filter :get_user

  def get_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    // You could also do error checking in before_filters
  end
```